# What is the most appropriate HTTP response code for a resource known NOT to exist?

Tags: http, http-headers

I wonder if there is a better choice than 404 when someone requests a page like http://www.example.com/page-that-never-existed-nor-will-ever-exist ("ever" meaning for the foreseeable future but for all intents and purposes: never ever).

For instance I get requests for pages that some "clever" crawlers think might exist based on the structure they have encountered on the website or elsewhere on the web. They are not misspellings but requests that I know to lead nowhere

I don't want to use `301 Moved Permanently` because nothing has moved and there is no logical destination to move to.
I don't want to use `410 Gone` because it was never there in the first place.

I also would like something more fitting than `404 Not Found` because I would really like to give the message "Does Not Exist": not just "Not Found, what happened? Who knows?". How can I tell a User-Agent that it is a waste of both our times to ask for it again?

Based on [HTTP 1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.5),  `404 Not Found` seems like the most correct option, because the definition ends with "or when no other response is applicable" but I am not fully satisfied with that. Any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered 403 Forbidden? It sounds like what you might be looking for and you can include a message in the body of the response that tells the client that the resource will never exist.

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
>   Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If
>   the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public
>   why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason
>   for the refusal in the entity. If the server does not wish to make
>   this information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not
>   Found) can be used instead.

Comment: I understand the reasoning but I don't think it's appropriate as there really is no interdiction. I just want to indicate that it's a waste of time (on both sides) to request said resource, that it's definitely a mistake on the UA's part.